# Single column elsarticle

Tags: two-column, columns, elsarticle

I cannot seem to figure out how to make a single column elsarticle. I would like to enforce my whole document to just use one column instead of two.

What am I missing?

```latex
\documentclass[5p,10pt,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

context:
I am writing a response letter. I would like to show some of the text changes I made in the revision in the native formatting, but I am adjusting the basic format to be better suited to the Q&A of the response letter.

Comment: BTW, this package comes with a manual.  See https://ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle?lang=en

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either remove the `5p` option, or use the `1p` option instead. The default options loaded are `a4paper`, `10pt`, `oneside`, `onecolumn` and `preprint`. You shouldn't worry about loading any of them, and the most important thing is to check the instructions of your specific journal. Refere to [this document](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/pdf_file/0008/56843/elsdoc-1.pdf) for more details on possible options.

```
\documentclass[times,1p]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do "1p" and "5p" refer to? How do they relate to those default options you mention?

Comment: @TimKuipers  -- Refere to [this document](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/pdf_file/0008/56843/elsdoc-1.pdf) for more details.

Comment: "3p" etc stand for a model 3+ journal, but I am unable to find out what that refers to.